# Is there any sense to make std::atomic<> objects with the qualifier - volatile?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Is there any sense to make atomic objects with the qualifier - volatile?

Use that:

```
volatile std::atomic<int> i(1);
```

instead of:

```
std::atomic<int> i(1);
```

Comment: [volatile vs. volatile](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no sense in making `std::atomic` also volatile, as inside the `std::atomic`, the code will deal with the possibility that the variable may change at any time, and that other processors may need to be "told" that it has changed (the "telling" other processors is not covered by `volatile`).

The only time you really need `volatile` is if you have a pointer to piece of hardware that your code is controlling - for example reading a counter in a timer, or a which frame buffer is active right now, or telling a network card where to read the data for the next packet to send.  Those sort of things are volatile, because the compiler can't know that the value of those things can change at any time.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Mind asking why there are `volatile` member functions of `std::atomic<T>` out there? If there is no necessity of a `volatile` atomic, why those `volatile` functions are defined in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it doesn't make sense.

Use `atomic` to allow the variable to be modified on one thread while other threads may be accessing it without explicit synchronisation.

Use `volatile` to control access to unusual memory locations (such as hardware registers), where every read and write must happen in the order specified by the program. A normal variable, atomic or otherwise, doesn't usually require such control.

The two concepts are unrelated to each other. In particular, do not confuse `volatile` with a keyword used in other languages to make variables atomic. In C++, `volatile` has nothing to do with thread interactions whatsoever.

Comment: Your first sentence is intriguing: when _does_ it make sense to declare an atomic object `volatile`? It seems, the only reasonable use could possibly be an aotmic object in unusual member...

Comment: @DietmarKühl: One could imagine a situation where one might want multi-threaded access to hardware registers or whatever, and both concepts might make sense. Unusual, but not beyond the realms of possibility.

Comment: That is what I thought but I doubt that it would be required to work! After all, any `std::atomic<T>` can be implemented using a mutex lock and a `T`, i.e., the memory layout of `std::atomic<T>` isn't known while it is known, at least, for some types.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yes, you're probably right; you'd want `atomic<volatile int>` there I guess. I wrote "usually" because I can't prove that it never makes sense, rather than because I think it might.

Comment: Can a `std::atomic<T>` value be located at a specific location - in other words, could we do something like `std::atomic<volatile int>* pAtomic = reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<volatile int>*(0xfce00000);` [assuming we know that 0xfce00000 is some good memory address in hardware-land? Just curious, and not complaining about the answer.