# atomic operation with volatile atomic variable

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

Why c++ atomic operations has an overloaded version for volatile `atomic<T>`?

When are we required declare `atomic<T>` as volatile and what is difference between `atomic<T>` and `volatile atomic<T>`?

Comment: *Why we must declare atomic<T> as volatile..*  Who said it?

Comment: @Nawaz I think it's a typo really asking "when are we required", I ask OP to confirm this.

Comment: @Nawaz OP is asking in what circumstances must we declare as volatile.

Comment: @self.: OP is not asking that (thought he might have that in his mind)

Comment: @Nawaz From the context it quite clear he had that "in mind".

Comment: Yes "when are we required"

Comment: @MohammadRB You can correct the question -> Edit.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18303405/is-there-any-sense-to-make-stdatomic-objects-with-the-qualifier-volatile

Comment: generalization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242578/volatile-overloading

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as with any other type: you need to volatile-qualify your atomic if you're performing atomic operations on a memory-mapped I/O register or otherwise require the semantics of volatile-qualified types (which are not related in any way to atomicity or to the inter-thread synchronization and memory ordering provided by atomic operations).

The standard has this to say about the `volatile` overloads for atomics (`29.6.5[atomics.types.operations.req]/3`)

> [ Note: Many operations are volatile-qualified. The “volatile as device register” semantics have not changed
>   in the standard. This qualification means that volatility is preserved when applying these operations to
>   volatile objects. It does not mean that operations on non-volatile objects become volatile. Thus, volatile
>   qualified operations on non-volatile objects may be merged under some conditions. —end note ]